# Measurement widget does not work with other widgets in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, measurements, widget

I am having an issue with the Measurement-Widget in combination with other widgets with the newest ArcGIS API for JavaScript (3.13).
With the sandbox, I was able to create a map which includes HomeButton, LocateButton, Scalebar, OverviewMap and BasemapGallery. All this works together. When I start to add the code of the Measurement-Widget, the other widgets disappear. So I removed some code from the -container and sfs, pacelsLayer, snapManager and layerInfos. With or without it, it doesn't matter. When I comment out this part:

```
//esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
//esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;
//esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService ("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");
```

the other widgets work again, but the Measurement-Widget tools are missing.

I tried also to build the homebutton inside of the following link, but it doesn't work.
http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_measurement

The Search/Geocoder-Widget doesn't work too...but there seems that it have a problem with the BasemapGallery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Part VII: Measurement-Widget</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">   

    <style>
      html, body, #mapDIV {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

     #HomeButtonDIV {
      position: absolute;
      top: 95px;
      left: 20px;
      z-index: 50;
        }

     #LocateButtonDIV {
      position: absolute;
      top: 135px;
      left: 20px;
      z-index: 50;
    }

    </style>

    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/"></script>

    <script>
      var map, home, locate, overviewMapDijit, scalebar, basemapGallery, sfs, parcelsLayer, snapManager, layerInfos, measurement;

      require([ "esri/map",
                "esri/dijit/HomeButton",
                "esri/dijit/LocateButton",
                "esri/dijit/OverviewMap",
                "esri/dijit/Scalebar",
                "esri/dijit/BasemapGallery",
                "esri/arcgis/utils",
                "dojo/parser",
                "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
                "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
                "dijit/TitlePane",

                "dojo/dom",
                "esri/Color",
                "dojo/keys",
                "esri/config",
                "esri/sniff",
                "esri/SnappingManager",
                "esri/dijit/Measurement",
                "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
                "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer",
                "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
                "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
                "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
                "dijit/form/CheckBox",

                "dojo/domReady!"],
                function(Map, HomeButton, LocateButton, OverviewMap, Scalebar, BasemapGallery, arcgisUtils, parser,
                dom, Color, keys, esriConfig, has, SnappingManager, Measurement, FeatureLayer, SimpleRenderer,
                GeometryService, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol
                ) {

        map = new Map("mapDIV", { //unsere DIV-ID
          basemap: "osm", 
          center: [13.734875, 51.034163], //laenge, breite
          zoom: 18 //zoomstufe
        });

                parser.parse();

                //esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
                //esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;
                //esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");


        home = new HomeButton({
            map: map
            }, "HomeButtonDIV");
            home.startup();

        geoLocate = new LocateButton({
            map: map
            }, "LocateButtonDIV");
            geoLocate.startup();

        overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
          map: map,
          visible: true
        });
        overviewMapDijit.startup();

        scalebar = new Scalebar({
            map: map,
            scalebarUnit: "dual",
            attachTo: "bottom-left"
            });

        basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
            showArcGISBasemaps: true,
            map: map
            }, "basemapGalleryDIV");
            basemapGallery.startup();

            basemapGallery.on("error", function(msg) {
            console.log("basemap gallery error:  ", msg);
            });

<!--        //sind die konturen der flaechen beim sandboxtest   
        sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol(
            "solid",
            new SimpleLineSymbol("solid", new Color([195, 176, 23]), 2), 
            null
            );
        //duerfte der Layer fuer die parzellen sein, die mir angezeigt werden bei der sandbox
        parcelsLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Louisville/LOJIC_LandRecords_Louisville/MapServer/0", {
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
            outFields: ["*"]
            });
            parcelsLayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(sfs));
            map.addLayers([parcelsLayer]);

        snapManager = map.enableSnapping({
            snapKey: has("mac") ? keys.META : keys.CTRL
            });
        //keine ahnung wofür das ist
        layerInfos = [{
            layer: parcelsLayer
            }];
            snapManager.setLayerInfos(layerInfos); -->


        measurement = new Measurement({
            map: map
            }, dom.byId("measurementDIV"));
            measurement.startup();



      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="claro">
    <div id="mapDIV"></div>
    <div id="HomeButtonDIV"></div>
    <div id="LocateButtonDIV"></div>

    <div style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:252px; z-Index:999;">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" 
                data-dojo-props="title:'Switch Basemap', closable:false, open:true">
                 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width:391px; height:221px; overflow:auto;">
                     <div id="basemapGalleryDIV"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:544px; z-Index:999;">
          <div id="titlePane" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title:'Measurement', closable:false, open:true">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width:391px; height:221px; overflow:auto;">
            <div id="measurementDIV"></div>
            <span style="font-size:smaller;padding:5px 5px;">Press <b>CTRL</b> to enable snapping.</span>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, I'd suggest you replace the html comments with /* javascript */ commments. Second, move the BorderContainer, ContentPane, and TitlePane references in your require() statement so that they're under the dijit/form/CheckBox reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules in your `require` are not matching with the variables in the function.

You need to move the modules

```
`dijit/layout/BorderContainer`,
`dijit/layout/ContentPane`,
`dijit/TitlePane`
```

to after

```
`esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol`.
```